# Can't find webdriver_manager module in PyCharm

Tags: python, webdriver-manager

I'm trying to get a headless webscraper going using firefox and geckodriver and I'm trying to get the paths using webdriver_manager.

I've run

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

and I'm trying to use this to open the browser

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=GeckoDriverManager().install())
```

However, I keep getting a runtime error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webdriver_manager'
```

I've already added the library to the python interpreter in PyCharm, but I just can't get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

I found another solution. Go to Python Packages at the bottom panel, search for "webdriver-manager" and install it manually

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem for a long while and I found a solution that actually worked for me:

```
python3 -m pip install webdriver_manager
```

All of my research told me in one form or another to run the following that never worked for me:

```
pip install webdriver_manager
```

Running the first command instead for whatever reason actually allowed me to utilize the module.

Answer (score 1):

First of all - do you use virtualenv or global env?
It's better to use virtualenv.
To create venv and activate it use this in your project directory

```sh
python3 -m venv .venv
source .venv/bin/activate (for macOS/linux)
.venv/bin/activate.bat (for Windows)
pip3 install webdriver_manager
```

In Pycharm then:

1. Open Pycharm "Settings" (for MacOS "Preferences")
2. Project->Python Interpreter
3. Select wheel->Add
4. Choose existing interpreter in .venv in your project directory

Cheers! Pycharm now sees the webdriver_manager imports.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same error and weirdly the problem was VCS and me pulling this project from Git.
If there are no other options at all, you could try this:

- close PyCharm
- delete the .idea/ folder of that project
- restart PyCharm and configure interpreter again

Somehow this .idea folder messed up the project. aber deleting everything came to normal for me.